# I need an XPATH to extract data from www.gsmarena.com

Tags: xpath, extract

I am doing a research about how mobile phones evolved over years so I need to create a database with specifications of as many phones is possible. I am trying to scrap data from GSM Arena website.

Example page: http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note7-8082.php

I am using XPATH that contains the label that precedes each value, example **//tr[contains (.,"Sensors")]/td[2]**

But there are some values, last one in category, with no preceding label.

**How do I pick this info:**

*Non-removable Li-Po 3500 mAh battery*

**or this ino:**

*Fast battery charging
Qi wireless charging (market dependent)
ANT+ support
S-Voice natural language commands and dictation
MP4/DivX/XviD/WMV/H.265 player
MP3/WAV/WMA/eAAC+/FLAC player
Photo/video editor
Document editor*

Do note that different phones have different number of rows on page, so using [number] in XPATH would pick different info from

http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note7-8082.php - need to pick 5th row of features

http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_sgh_600-49.php - need to pick 8th row of features

Answer (score 1):

To select rows without label in Battery section you have to use this xpath:

```
//tbody[.//th[contains(.,'Battery')]]//td[@class="ttl" and not(*)]/following-sibling::td
```

To select info from features use this

```
//tbody[.//th[contains(.,'Features')]]//td[@class="ttl" and not(*)]/following-sibling::td
```

To select Camera features

```
//tbody[.//th[contains(.,'Camera')]]//td[@class="ttl" and contains(.,'Features')]/following-sibling::td
```

To select Loudspeaker in Sound Category

```
//tbody[.//th[contains(.,'Sound')]]//td[@class="ttl" and contains(.,'Loudspeaker')]/following-sibling::td
```

Comment: IT WORKED! And I initially though that is impossible to scrap something without a preceding label.But I have found another problem: //tr[contains (.,"Features")]/td[2] instead of picking just data of Features label in Camera category, it pick also all data under Features category. Also //tr[contains (.,"Loudspeaker")]/td[2] picks two data because they have same label. How to pick separately Loudspeaker under Sound and Tests category? Can you help with another XPATH?

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer to add more answers. After 1 month I noticed that Technology have a button EXPAND showing 2G, 3G, 4G bands, so I improved my database by including them too, but at certain phones (example http://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_7_plus-8065.php) there are 2 rows for each band, how do I pick the second row (CDMA 800 / 1900 / 2100 - A1661) which do not have any preceding label?